# Python share a function between processes and perform other tasks while waiting

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I would like to use the python3 multiprocessing module for the following setup:

I have two python functions func_1 and func_2 that perform the following tasks:

- func_1 has a parameter my_param and returns a tuple (new_param, my_list).
- func_2 takes as input a list and performs some transformations to it.

A process should access func_1, lock this resource until (new_param, my_list) are returned by func_1, then make (new_param, my_list) available to the next process in the line. While waiting for the resource func_1, a process should be running func_2 on the input list it was previously given.

I am new to multiprocessing and any suggestions on how I could set up the above workflow is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have tried.

Comment: I do not know how to get started, so I do not have some useful code to share. Which parts of the multiprocessing module are useful for such a scenario? A queue? I have researched on other SO posts, but I couldn't find something that addresses my issue.

Comment: But there is still tonnes of stuff on SO about `multiprocessing`. You should be able to harvest *something* which at least starts some processes. When you get stuck, you will then have a question to ask.